# How come when a new message is received, all previous messages' timestamps are set to the same as the new one?

Tags: java, android

My chat output is looking below,

[image]

In above image,The right side chat's are,Chat message I was send to others  and left side chat's are, I am receive response from others.Now my issue is when i am receive any response message while chat the time of that chat is displayed along with that message displayed properly,But when i am receiving second response message from others the time of first chat(receive message) is changed as second chat(receive message) time similarly that i am explained above image.How to fix this issue anyone help me.

My programming code for chat is below,

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ChatMessageObjects m = messagesItems.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 1) {
                        // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_right,
                                null);
                        //TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
                        TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                        //date and time declared on date here
                        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                        try {
                            //actualDate contains date "(i.e)27-Aug-2015 6:20:25 am/pm" in this format
                            String actualDate = m.getDate();
                            Date FormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse(actualDate);
                            //actualDate converted from "(i.e)27-Aug-2015 6:20:25 am/pm" to "6:20 pm" in this
                            //format for display the chat time for every chat message .
                            dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(FormatDate);

                            // lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        date.setText(dateResult);
                        txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

                    } else {
                        //if (m.getMessage() != null) {
                            // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_left,
                                    null);
                            //TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
                            TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                            //date and time added here
                            final TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                           //Time coding start from here
                            String actualDate = m.getDate();
                            if (actualDate == null) {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                                String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                           //Time set here
                                date.setText(strDate);

                            }
                            m.setDate(strDate);

                            txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

                        }

                    //}

                }

                return convertView;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `m`? a model? When is it set?

Comment: m is variable for getting chat message objects

Comment: i am edited my code please check that ..

Comment: When is the date set for incoming messages?

Comment: while receiving the message, instantly the time set along with that message.

Comment: Can you include the code where you do that? Because it seems that is not working

Comment: i have that code in else condition..I am mentioned that code in commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String actualDate = m.getDate();
if (actualDate == null) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    //Time set here
    date.setText(strDate);
}
```

What you do here is you get the value of `m.getDate()` which is null because it is not yet set. Then you use the **current** time to put int the TextView. That is fine for new messages, but not for messages that are older.

What you forgot to do here, is *set* the date of `m`. You need something like `m.setDate(strDate)` at the end of the if.

Because you currently don't change `m`'s date value, everytime you try to get it with `String actualDate = m.getDate();`, it will be null, causing the date to be 'reset' to the current date.

---

> Now when i am receive the message the time for that message viewed.But when i am receive the second message the time of first message doesn't viewed(time of first message is empty).

This is because now only the date is set when the actualDate is null. You can solve this easily. It could look like this

```
String actualDate = m.getDate();
if (actualDate == null) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    m.setDate(strDate);
}

//Time set here
date.setText(m.getDate());
```

Comment: sorry for delay response i have problem in jboss server so i am not test my app.I should response you after that server problem solved.

Comment: can you please check my else condition..I am added m.setDate(strDate)..Now when i am receive the message the time for that message viewed.But when i am receive the second message the time of first message doesn't viewed(time of first message is empty).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response..now it is working fine..thanks for your help..if any queries about my app i am definitely ask you in future..

Comment: can you please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399401/how-to-avoid-display-the-time-on-next-layout-when-on-tap-the-listview .i am explained my issue please give solution for that..